# algorithm Knapsack with 2 restrictions

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, np

Iv'e been working on a project and i encountered the following scenario:
Need to choose N = 2 boxes from a set of M while M > N with the best sum of weights but with 2 restrictions:

- We can’t choose the same box color
- We can’t choose the same box id

The Boxes comes sorted with the highest weight on top

[image]

I choose (Red1,Blue2) with the Naive algorithm starting with the highest weight Red1, we couldn’t add Blue1 because we had the same ID 1, and couldnt add Red2 as well because we had Red box with the weight of 10, we ended up with with total weight of 11, but we could end up with 18.9 if we choose Blue1 & Red2
N can be bigger than 2.

Is it an NP-Hard problem ?
Any better Solutions with a good run time efficiency ?

Comment: Is there a bound on the number of different colors or the number of different IDs?

Comment: 2 bounds/constraints, result should have different colors and different ids with the highest sum of weight that's possible

Answer (score 0):

We can use DP Solution with complexity `O(2^color * 2^id * M * N)` or Backtracking+Pruning with complexity `O(M choose N)`

So it depends on how big the constraint for M, N, color and id.

Comment: I thought of splitting it depends on the the size of N and M
N is mostly 9-10 and M is being changed, can be 10 - 350

Comment: with N<=10 and M<=350, backtracking + efficient pruning can solved your problem.